# How to change values of a sub-list by values of another list

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

This is what I have:

```
a = [['a0', '0'], ['a1', '1'], ['a2', '2']]
b = ['b0', 'b1', 'b2']
```

What I want is to replace all first values of each sub-list in `a` with the values in `b`. So this would be the desired output:

```
d = [['b0', '0'], ['b1', '1'], ['b2', '2']]
```

This is my code:

```
def make_new_list(a,b):    
    for sublist in a:
        for i in range(len(b)):
             sublist[0] = b[i]        
    return a
```

This is what i get with this code:

```
[['b2', '0'], ['b2', '1'], ['b2', '2']]
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: "What you want" isn't legal Python.

Comment: @ScottHunter Why not?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis: Unbalanced brackets; colon in a list.  Type it into an interpreter.

Comment: @ScottHunter I assume these are just typos..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[[b1, a1[1]] for a1, b1 in zip(a, b)]
```

Comment: the inner container is a list according to OP

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(0, 3):
    temp = a[i]
    d.append([b[i], temp[1]])
```

Try that

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is the way the loops are constructed. The inner one in particular which executes 3 times for every sublist in `a`. You do not want that. Below is a fixed version of your script:

```
a=[['a0','0'],['a1','1'],['a2','2']]
b=['b0','b1','b2']

def make_new_list(a,b):

    for i, sublist in enumerate(a):
        sublist[0] = b[i]
    return a

print(make_new_list(a, b))  # [['b0', '0'], ['b1', '1'], ['b2', '2']]
```

More Pythonic yet would be the following:

```
a= [[x[0], x[1][1]] for i, x in enumerate(zip(b, a))]
print(a)  # [['b0', '0'], ['b1', '1'], ['b2', '2']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip` and a list comprehension like so:

```
>>> a=[['a0','0'],['a1','1'],['a2','2']]
>>> b=['b0','b1','b2']
>>> [[bl]+al[1:] for al, bl in zip(a,b)]
[['b0', '0'], ['b1', '1'], ['b2', '2']]
```

Or, use `numpy` slice assignments:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> ar=np.array([['a0','0'],['a1','1'],['a2','2']])
>>> ar[:,0]=b
>>> ar
array([['b0', '0'],
       ['b1', '1'],
       ['b2', '2']], 
      dtype='|S2')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this without zip:

```
a = [['a0', '0'], ['a1', '1'], ['a2', '2']]
b = ['b0', 'b1', 'b2']

new_list = [[b[i], a[i][1]] for i in range(len(b))]
```